# C# Return a boolean from Main

Tags: c#

im trying to return a boolean from my Main (so i can get the output into another program) here are the [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz5f2.png) im getting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it (copy-pasted as text). Also copy-paste the full and complete build output (as text!) into the question.

Comment: As for the problem of "returning" data, why not *print* the data and let the other program read it? Or use some kind of other [IPC way of sharing data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). However, if you want to return a boolean result, why not return it as a simple `int` value or `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return bool from `Main`:

> Main can either have a void, int, or, starting with C# 7.1, Task, or
> `Task<int>` return type.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line).